# Error de columna duplicada con migration laravel 7

Tags: laravel, eloquent

que tal. Estoy iniciando un proyecto con Laravel 7 para suscripciones de contenido en video, lo primero que estoy haciendo es la creación de usuarios, roles de usuarios y campos relacionados para stripe y cashier, el código de la migración es el siguiente, por ahora no estoy trabajando con seeders ni factory.

```
public function up()
{

    Schema::create('roles', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id')->default(Role::STUDENT);
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
        $table->string('picture')->nullable();
        //Cashier Columns
        $table->string('card_brand')->nullable();
        $table->string('card_last_four')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('trial_ends_at')->nullable();

        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });


    Schema::create('suscriptions', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('stripe_id');
        $table->string('stripe_plan');
        $table->integer('quantity');
        $table->timestamp('trial_ends_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });


    Schema::create('user_social_accounts', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->string('provider');
        $table->string('provider_uid');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('user_social_accounts');
    Schema::dropIfExists('suscriptions');
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    Schema::dropIfExists('roles');
}
```

En el momento que ejecuto la migración con alguno de estos comandos:

```
php artisan migrate
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

La respuesta de error que me aparece en consola es la siguiente:

```
QLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'card_brand' (SQL: alter table `users` add `stripe_id` varchar(255) null, add `card_brand` varchar(255) null, add `card_last_four` varchar(4) null, add `trial_ends_at` timestamp null)
```

Me parece bastante extraño ya que la columna no esta duplicada y ya ejecute un *rollback* a la migración, ademas de limpiar el cache de *artisan*. No se si sea buena idea o si sea necesario borrar la base de datos y volverla a crear.

Comment: A parte de esta migración ¿estás ejecutando alguna otra?

Comment: No, es la unica migración que ejecuto.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando instalas cashier en tu proyecto laravel y ejecutas una migración el mismo cashier altera la tabla usuarios y agrega las columnas que el paquete necesita.

```
   Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id')->default(Role::STUDENT);
    $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
    $table->string('picture')->nullable();

    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```